# Creating a count of items that fits a criteria at each snapshot in time

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a postgres query that gives me a snapshot of the number of open cases at a point in time. I have a table with a list of timestamps, which will be the snapshots in time that I will be using. The second table is a list of cases, with a CASE_OPEN_TIME and a CASE_CLOSED_TIME. Eventually, I am trying to create a table that has a column with the snapshot timestamps, and the number of cases that are still open at that timestamp. Appreciate your help and advice on how I can solve this problem. Thanks in advance :)

| SNAPSHOT |
| --- |
| 2022-07-10 10:00:00 |
| 2022-07-09 10:00:00 |
| 2022-07-08 10:00:00 |
| 2022-07-07 10:00:00 |
| 2022-07-06 10:00:00 |
| 2022-07-05 10:00:00 |

| CASE_ID | CASE_OPEN_TIME | CASE_CLOSED_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-05 04:00:00 | 2022-07-05 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-07-06 09:00:00 | 2022-07-08 12:00:00 |
| 3 | 2022-07-08 09:00:00 | 2022-07-08 13:00:00 |
| 4 | 2022-07-10 08:00:00 | 2022-07-10 09:00:00 |

Final Output:

| SNAPSHOT | COUNT_OPEN_CASES |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-10 10:00:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-09 10:00:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-08 10:00:00 | 2 |
| 2022-07-07 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-06 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-05 10:00:00 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your snapshot table is called `SNAPSHOT` and the cases `CASES` isn't the result you want

```
SELECT
    SNAPSHOT.SNAPSHOT_TIME,
    COUNT(*) NR_CASES
FROM
    SNAPSHOT LEFT OUTER JOIN CASES ON SNAPSHOT.SNAPSHOT_TIME >= CASE_OPEN_TIME AND SNAPSHOT.SNAPSHOT_TIME <= CASE_CLOSSED_TIME
GROUP BY
    SNAPSHOT.SNAPSHOT_TIME
```

the left outer join would give you the snapshot even if there are no cases

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, i had a brain fart moment -- didn't think of using this join condition!